# Could not locate the bindings file in nodejs Android

Tags: android, node.js, termux

I tried to run an application on nodejs in Android using Termux. When I start npm , it said could not locate the bindings file. My device is rooted.

nodejs v10.15.3

npm 6.4.1

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:91
  throw err
  ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 →/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/ref/build/binding.node
 →/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/ref/build/Debug/binding.node
 →/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/ref/build/Release/binding.node
 →/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/ref/out/Debug/binding.node
 →/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/ref/Debug/binding.node
 →/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/ref/out/Release/binding.node
 →/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/ref/Release/binding.node
 →/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/ref/build/default/binding.node
 →/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/ref/compiled/10.15.3/android/arm64/binding.node
at bindings (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:88:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/ref/lib/ref.js:5:47)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/IoT-blockchain-Std/node_modules/ffi/lib/ffi.js:6:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! IoT-blockchain-Std@1.0.0 start: `node build/main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the IoT-blockchain-Std@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I seen some people solve this issue by downgrading the nodejs. I tried different ways which can be used in Ubuntu to downgrade the nodejs, but it does not work in Termux. Is there and method to downgrade the nodejs in Termux?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the same issue installing the missing file. 
In your case it is `biding.node`, so you should do: `npm install binding`